# rainmeter calculating percentage of a school year minus holidays and weekends

Tags: rainmeter

How can I, in rainmeter, calculate the number of school days between August 19th 2014 and a certain date? As in, I want to be able to calculate the percentage of how far into the school year today is. So far I have something that calculates the number of DAYS between to dates, but I need to be able to calculate the number of school days too.